# How to import DLL libraries in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, compilation

I would like to use an external precompiled library for Fast Fourier Transform.
The files provided are all .dll files with corresponding .def files. In the instructions, it writes that I should create a .lib import library file with lines like:

lib /def:libfftw3f-3.def

Should I just copy the statements in a txt file and rename it to lib? And where I should put this .lib file? And how do I include in my project? Would I still need to state "#include <XXX.dll>" or would the lib file do?

Also, the dll seems to be in C language, would I be able to call its functions in C++?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is a typical obstacle they put in the way of newbie programmers to filter their mailing list.  If you can't complete that step then they don't want to hear from you since the odds you'll know what to do next are very low.  Pretty cynical, very pragmatic.  The step they intentionally left out is the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  Click that shortcut to be able to run lib.exe.  If you still don't know what to do with the .lib file you get then you're going too fast.  Write your own code first, try creating your own static libraries, make all the mistakes you need to make.

Comment: Thanks! That solves it...yeah it's quite mean they left it out...and it's so nice there're still people like you out there who would help us newbies out:) The command prompt generates lib files out of the given def and dll, and simply importing them into VS makes them work.

Answer (score 0):

[Command prompt: FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-8) is a good place to start. You need a .h header file as well as the resulting link .lib, or you can use the .h header file and then use LoadLibrary/GetProcessAddress. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64tkc9y5.aspx)